# A way to disable SSL using python MySQLdb connector

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, mysql-python

Opening a connection using SSL with python connector gives me following error:

```
MySQLdb.connect(host='host',user='user,passwd='xxx',db='xxx',)

OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: ASN: unknown key OID type')
```

The same is when I am using bash mysql command:

```
mysql -p -u user -h host
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ASN: unknown key OID type
```

The only way around I have found was to use --ssl-mode=DISABLED

```
mysql -p -u user -h host --ssl-mode=DISABLED
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

Is there any way I am able to mimic this using python connector? 
I am using mysql v 5.7.26 on Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.5.2.

Comment: For the future generations, the issue was solved by changing the connector to the one from mysql-connector-python. It's function mysql.connector.connect has kwarg ssl_disabled = True.

Answer (score 8):

Connect to mysql/mariaDB without SSL in python:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

mysql_config = {
        'user': 'DB-user',
        'password': 'userpassword',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'your-DB-name',
        'port': '3306',
        'ssl_disabled': True
    }

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
    if cnx.is_connected():
        print('connected to database') 

except Error as e:
    print("mysql DB connection error")
    print(e)
```

Also see full documentation: [Mysql Connector/Python Connection Arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html).

If you want to connect via mysqlx, see examples on [Getting started with mysqlx](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/tutorials/getting_started.html).

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: Unsupported argument 'ssl_disabled'` error

Answer (score 4):

As the original poster mentioned in his comment, one of the most convenient ways to disable SSL in Python — is by using `pip install mysql-connector-python` and then employing the `ssl_disabled` key.

mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, port=PORT, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, **ssl_disabled=True/False**)

So the code would look like this:

```
    import mysql.connector as mysql
    
    db_connection = mysql.connect(host=HOST, database=DATABASE, port=PORT, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, ssl_disabled=True)
    print("Connected to:", db_connection.get_server_info())
    db_handler = connection.cursor()
    db_handler.execute("SELECT * FROM your_table")
    fetch_result = db_handler.fetchall()
    for item in fetch_result:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who get `AttributeError: Unsupported argument 'ssl_disabled'`, do this:

```bash
pip uninstall mysql-python
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

[python-mysql](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/#description) is a legacy client version, with latest version released in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

According to manual, "ssl" key manages, if present, the ssl protocol. So I supose passing a void dictionary on this tag, may work for you. (Works in may
Try this:

```
mysql_config = {
        'user': 'DB-user',
        'password': 'userpassword',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'your-DB-name',
        'port': '3306',
        'ssl': {}
    }
self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(**mysql_config )
self.connection.autocommit(True)
return database.DBOK
```

Comment: I just want to report you a typo, in case you want to fix it: the sentence _"(Works in may Try this:"_ sounds some way truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient) also supports the `ssl_mode` param since version 2.0.0. With that you can also do:

`MySQLdb.connect(host='host', user='user', passwd='xxx', db='xxx', ssl_mode='DISABLED')`